# scrollRowIntoView not working in jquery-ui dialog box

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-dialog, slickgrid

I am using slick grid for displaying item list. 
The list is populated using `$.ajax` call in a `jquery-ui dialog box`.

I have requirement to scroll to the position of previously selected item.
Hence, I use following function to scroll and select previously selected item:

```
function SetDefaultItemSelected() {

        var selectedKey = 16; // hardcoded but there is logic to get previous item

        for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < myItemDataView.getLength(); rowIndex++) {
            var gridRow = myItemDataView.getItem(rowIndex);
            if (gridRow.Key === selectedKey) {
                myItemGrid.setSelectedRows([rowIndex]);

                //TODO: check why the scrollRowIntoView is not working
                myItemGrid.scrollRowIntoView(rowIndex);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Output is something like this:

(There are 22 rows in total and I had previously selected 16th  row)
I am not sure why it is hiding the top 3 rows and not scrolling to 16th row.

[image: Slick Grid with data populated]

**UPDATE 1:**

Just checked that if I add the button and bind its click event with the the above function, the scrolling magically works.
But, I am not sure what wrong am I doing in calling the function just after creation of grid?
Please help.

Could it be possible bug as functionality is working on page but not on jquery-ui dialog?

**UPDATE 2:**

I created new MVC3 application and tried to implement the same thing - Called the LoadData function by $.ajax and populated the slick grid and then tried to select default id.

I realized that the issue comes up only if the grid is in jquery-ui dialog.
The same grid on the page works normally.

Could it possibly be a bug that slick grid scroll works on page and not in dialog loaded by ajax call??

Please help and let me know in case I need to share sample code.

**UPDATE 3:**

Added the sample code. Any help would be much appreciated!!

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/slickgrid/CUjY3H1F_zM

Answer (score 0):

**WORKAROUND:**

Hello All,

There are 2 jquery ajax calls in my sample code (attached in google groups link in UPDATE 3 in the question):

1) `.load()` to load the empty jquery-dialog PartialView

2) `.ajax()` called on `document.ready` of partialView.js file to load the slick grid data.
(*partialView.js is referenced in PartialView.cshtml*)

While trying many things, I found that when I put `debugger;` just before the 2nd `.ajax()` call and passed this debug point in chrome developer toolbar, the issue didn't seem to come.

So, I  removed `debugger;` and thought of introducing delay of 500 ms

`window.setTimeout(functionToBeDelayed, requiredDelay);`

and the functionality started to behave as expected.

I am still not sure how these nested ajax calls is causing the issue. But, as of now, 500 ms delay has done trick for me.

**As of now, applying workaround but definitely looking forward for some better solution**.